# Open window with predefined size

Tags: javascript, adobe-brackets, brackets-shell

Does anyone know how to open new with specific size?
`brackets` object does not contain any function to do that - there's only 2 `brackets.app` and `brackets.fs` object. Also if you try to open new window with

`window.open("http://stackoverflow.com","some title","width=500,height=500");`

it won't set the window size.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: What is the programming language?

Comment: i use the JavaScript. I took [this](http://clintberry.com/2013/native-desktop-javascript/) site as a sample. seems that i need to create some function in C++/Objectiv-C to have window creating option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a bug in [brackets-shell](https://github.com/adobe/brackets-shell) that the size you specify is getting ignored. (It could also be bug in CEF, the underlying Chromium wrapper that brackets-shell uses, but [this](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/issues/detail?id=467) implies it normally works in vanilla CEF – I'm guessing it's broken by the brackets-shell code that remembers your last window size across launches).

***However***, it's not a good idea to open an arbitrary website inside the Brackets shell itself. For one thing, you won't get back/forward buttons, or an address bar, or any of the other standard browser functionality. If you want to open an external website, use `NativeApp.openURLInDefaultBrowser()` instead (though just like clicking a link in any other app, you won't get to pick the window size). Or if you're building some UI that's more like a Brackets feature (not a remote URL), then it'd be much easier to use in-window popups instead – see the [`Dialogs` API](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/blob/master/src/widgets/Dialogs.js).

Answer (score 0):

That is how you open a new window, and set the size. I would assume you are coming across something else in your code, that is causing an error that you are not seeing.

Try binding it to a event call, like during a click event. Posting the code this applies to will help.

Answer (score 0):

> > I'm guessing it's broken by the brackets-shell code that remembers your last window size across launches

Can anyone point to this code so I can take a look at it?  Just get me close...